# Bootstrapping collections for performance

Tags: data-structures, collections, bootstrapping

In his seminal [thesis](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf), Chris Okasaki described the technique of data-structural bootstrapping. What work, if any, has been done to use this technique to improve locality in data structures?

For example, balanced binary trees are commonly used to create purely functional sets and dictionaries but a hash trie of small arrays are often significantly faster due to improved locality.

Comment: Here are [some citations](http://scholar.google.com.au/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&cites=8384406061283566134&scipsc=):

Comment: This might be better suited to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try references to his book by Haskell or Clojure folk rather than just the CMU pdf : e.g.,

[http://www.amazon.com/Purely-Functional-Structures-Chris-Okasaki/dp/0521663504](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521663504)

There was a question here on SO at :

[What is the benefit of purely functional data structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399837/what-is-the-benefit-of-purely-functional-data-structure)

There is also Clojure area this :

https://github.com/viksit/clojure-datastructures

And there was this on SE :

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1539/whats-new-in-purely-functional-data-structures-since-okasaki

Hope something there provides a basis for a search that bears results :-)

You may have to use an academic or biz ref search engine and you may want to look at poster sessions at a conf because search is not obvious here, e.g., Mercury can generate Erlang code ... so searching caching and locality with respect to performance in functional programming in some hardware area dealing with latency.

Canada'a National Research Council (NRC) had some work going on ... you could try a search of their pub's/notices/reports

But note: a search with

bigdata latency locality NRC 2012

gives rather different result from

bigdata functional latency locality NSF 2012

( and I would next drop the 2012 and try using the google search tool date range option for recent results)